# Show sidenav in large screens by default and collapse on smaller screens

Tags: css, materialize

I'm using the sidenav component of Materialize CSS, what I would like to do is to show the sidenav on large screens and collapse it on smaller screens.

```js
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
            var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container section">
            <a href="#" class="sidenav-trigger" data-target="sidebar">
                <i class="material-icons">
                    menu
                </i>
            </a>

            <ul class="sidenav active" id="sidebar">
                <li>
                    <div class="user-view">
                        <div class="background">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/536/354"  alt="">
                        </div>

                        <a href="#" >
                            <img class="circle" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/536/354" alt="">
                        </a>

                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="name white-text">Midori Pavlichenko</span>
                        </a>

                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="email white-text">hyperschnell11@outlook.sk</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="material-icons">edit</i> Some element
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="material-icons">local_phone</i>
                        Hello
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="material-icons">mail</i> Some other
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

At the moment it is collapsed for every screen, I want it to show by default on large screens and to collapse it for smaller screens, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Note: the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @Rob didn't realize, the html5 template was generated with a snippet from vscode

Comment: Microsoft has a lot still to learn about published standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.sidenav .sidenav-fixed`-class for the ul. This will always be open on large screens (cannot be collapsed as of now) and will open a modal drawer on medium and small screens. Look at [Sidenav variations](https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html#variations) in the documentation for more infos.